# Omit selection if less than 2 values are found

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that i join to get the data I want, company_details, officer_details and company_officer that join the two. My query right now takes officers that work for more than 2 companies and have not resigned.

I want to add to this query to only get companies that have more than 1 worker (after applying all the previous requirements). S

Company_Details

[image]
Company_Officer

[image]

Officer_Details

[image]

```
SELECT 
                            CD.Company_ID,
                            CD.Company_Name,
                            CD.Company_Index,
                            OD.Officer_ID,
                            OD.Officer_Name,
                            CO.Officer_Role
                        FROM
                            Company_Details CD
                        INNER JOIN Company_Officer CO 
                           ON CD.Company_ID = CO.Company_ID
                        INNER JOIN Officer_Details OD 
                           ON CO.Officer_ID = OD.Officer_ID
                        WHERE CD.Company_Index<>'' AND 
                              CO.Resigned_On='' AND
                              CO.Officer_ID IN
                               ( SELECT CO2.officer_id
                                 FROM   Company_Officer CO2
                                 INNER JOIN Company_Details CD2
                                 ON CO2.Company_ID = CD2.Company_ID
                                 WHERE CO2.Resigned_On='' AND CD2.Company_Index<>''
                                 GROUP  BY CO2.officer_id
                                 HAVING Count( DISTINCT CO2.company_id ) > 1 
                               )
                        ORDER BY `CD`.`Company_Name` ASC, `CD`.`Company_ID` ASC;
```

In the image below you can see the result of my current query. The highlighted 2 rows I would want to omit as you can see those companies only have one employee and I want to get rid from this selection companies with only one employee.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

just add another predicate to the Where clause

```
SELECT  CD.Company_ID, CD.Company_Name, CD.Company_Index,
    OD.Officer_ID, OD.Officer_Name, CO.Officer_Role
FROM Company_Details CD
    JOIN Company_Officer CO 
        ON CD.Company_ID = CO.Company_ID
    JOIN Officer_Details OD 
        ON CO.Officer_ID = OD.Officer_ID
WHERE CD.Company_Index<>'' 
     AND CO.Resigned_On='' 
     AND CO.Officer_ID IN
        ( SELECT CO2.officer_id
          FROM Company_Officer CO2
             JOIN Company_Details CD2
                  ON CO2.Company_ID = CD2.Company_ID
          WHERE CO2.Resigned_On='' AND CD2.Company_Index<>''
          GROUP  BY CO2.officer_id
          HAVING Count( DISTINCT CO2.company_id ) > 1)
And not Exists (Select * from company_officer
                Where Company_Id = cd.Company_Id 
                Having count(*) < 1)
ORDER BY `CD`.`Company_Name` ASC, `CD`.`Company_ID` ASC;
```

also, you could simplify the second predicate using `Exists` instead of `In`

```
SELECT  CD.Company_ID, CD.Company_Name, CD.Company_Index,
    OD.Officer_ID, OD.Officer_Name, CO.Officer_Role
FROM Company_Details CD
    JOIN Company_Officer CO 
        ON CD.Company_ID = CO.Company_ID
    JOIN Officer_Details OD 
        ON CO.Officer_ID = OD.Officer_ID
WHERE Not Exists
        (Select * FROM Company_Officer
         WHERE officer_id = od.officer_id 
            and Resigned_on = ''
         Having count(*) <= 2)
     And Not Exists 
        (Select * from company_officer
         Where Company_Id = cd.Company_Id 
         Having count(*) <= 1)
ORDER BY `CD`.`Company_Name` ASC, `CD`.`Company_ID` ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you for response but I have just tried that and I get 1052 results which is the same as my query. Companies with single employees are not omitted.

Comment: Had the exists backwards, try it again

Comment: The older query gives me still 1052 results and the new one 390 but it still kept all those companies with one employee.

Comment: Your first query: http://i.imgur.com/gI1GrwG.png your new query: http://i.imgur.com/IHYJ9My.png my query: http://i.imgur.com/8OHnjp9.png

Comment: Based on what you have in Company_Officer, the `CompanyId` is 211 for all the rows.  IS this a typo, or is the data actually like that?

Comment: It is just this part of the database so it is like that for this section. There is a row for each Officer. Here is a bigger picture: http://i.imgur.com/m8O8o33.png (there are many more)

Comment: then just run this: `Select * from company_officer
         Where Company_Id = 6
         Having count(*) <= 1`  and report what the results are.  If Acacia is not in the results then it DOES have more than one officer.

Comment: I just did no results i.e. empty, but my query takes into consideration only officers that have not resigned (resigned_on is = '') and only officers that work for more than 1 company at a time. That is why from my selection there was only one person because he is the only one working for more than just Acacia. And after all those filters I want to remove companies with only 1 person.

Comment: WELL then that is another requirement that NEEDs to be mentioned in your question sir. So your statement that you want to remove companies with only one officer is not correct. Rather, you want to remove companies which have only one officer that has not resigned and works for more than one company.... That's not the same thing.

Comment: Restate your question with accurate requirements.

Comment: 'My query right now takes officers that work for more than 2 companies and have not resigned.

I want to add to this query to only get companies that have more than 1 worker (after applying all the previous requirements).' 
that is first paragraph in my question.